# Change font and font size of CodeLens in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have enabled CodeLens for Visual Studio Code for TypeScript. The question is how I can change font and font size of it?

[image]

Comment: [custom css and js](https://github.com/be5invis/vscode-custom-css) extension + open dev tools => find element class => apply css style

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commit has finally landed, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/16038#issuecomment-724274684

The settings will be

```
editor.codeLensFontSize
editor.codeLensFontFamily
```

In v1.52.  Or just search for `codelens` in the Settings UI.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible as of VSCode 1.14

We are tracking a feature request for this here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/16038